# Contour Lines exported as raster in Illustrator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, contour, illustrator

I am trying to export contour lines from arcgis to illustrator to finish the map. I have tried to export the map with "vectorize layers with bitmap markers/fills" option, but it still opens as a raster in illustrator

Comment: export to svg import to illustrator - you do not mention versions of ArcGIS or Adobe Illustrator.

Answer (score 1):

Bitmap markers are the pictorial symbols such as little fire trucks or trees sometimes used to represent points. A contour line is just a vector feature. See [Exporting to PDF](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/map/map-export-and-print/exporting-to-pdf.htm) for tips on how map features export to Adobe software. "If a layer contains picture marker or picture fill symbology, use the option Vectorize picture markers/fills, found on the Format tab of the Options panel. This prevents rasterization of layers below picture markers and fills."

Comment: The link you posted solved it. The issue was that I had the contours set to 80% transparency